# Drag Player Object using Physics 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to drag a player object to throw coming obstacles in the way. For this purpose, I require to hold the player object and using it, I require to hit upcoming obstacles in the gameplay.

Basically currently I am working on this type of gameplay:
[Rise Up Game - Level 40+ 7851 High Score!!!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fh2gUZPCnfo)

At present I am trying to hit obstacles using this setup:

```
void Update()
 {  
     Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
     Rigidbody2D.position = mousePos;  
 }
```

Here are the inspector settings:
[image]

Still, the player hitting is jerky or not smooth. Multiple times obstacles get fixed within a player object.

So how to make this hitting proper?

Comment: Update the position in FixedUpdate instead of Update.  Remove the PointEffector component.  Make sure the RigidBody is set to Kinematic.

Comment: No, these changes not throwing upcoming obstacles away as you hit them. Please check the reference game video so you better understand this. - If I make Kinemetic then all things get mix-up when you hit.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment, you need to set the rigid body to Kinematic because it moves and you are modifying its position in code instead of via the physics simulation.

The PointEffector applies a constant force instead of a contact force, and needs to be removed.

If you are getting "tunneling" you need to set the collision detection to continuous.  If you are getting extreme bouncing or other glitchy behavior, try changing the mass and the properties on the physic material.

[image: inspector screenshot]
[image: result]